# How to fix "Warning: Use of the "var" keyword is deprecated"?

Tags: solidity

[image]

I tried using `auto instructor = instructors[_address]` it gives me the error:
`DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the variable first with their type and then assign them to their respective value. In your case it is:

```
Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address]
```

Comment: It didn't work but i added `storage` like this: `Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];` then it worked. So is it safe to use `storage` since I am inserting something in the Blockchain?

Comment: yeah probably. I'll edit my answer, but from what I know var is deprecated and now you have to put the type directly, like the way it's done in c++. `type variableName = someValue;`